# '%20/' is getting added to sample request URL

Tags: jmeter

I am performing load testing with Jmeter with below parameter.

```
UDV: 
Name: base_url
Value: clinical-web2.com

Server Name or IP: ${base_url}
Path:   /
```

Now Sample is getting failed and after observing 'View Result Tree' listener url in Reuest tab is: 'https://clinical-web2.com/%20/'

Don't know why '%20/' is getting added in url.

Comment: maybe you have some special charachters in your link like "è" "ò" or something else

Answer (score 2):

%20 is typically what the browser substitutes spaces with, so maybe check if there's any random space in your generated URL.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, but as You check above i did not added any space in UDV and Path also. So what can be reason.

Comment: in your configuration we can see that the path slash is under the a of Name so there is a space in front the slash. This comes to `clinical-web2.com/ /` which is url-encoded what you mention